# Route path in named outlet

Tags: angular

Simply put is something like this possible ?

```
[routerLink]="['page1','page2',{ outlets: { myoutlet: ['page3','page4'] } }]"
```

How would a route config look like ? With lazy loading if possible.

Edit:

ok, so it looks like the above case isn't possible. So i have rearrange my routes to something like this ....

```
const mainRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainIndexComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'page1',
        component: Page1Component,
        outlet: 'mynamed'
      },
      {
        path: 'page2',
        component: Page2Component,
        outlet: 'mynamed'
      },
      {
        path: 'form',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'first',
            component: FirstFormComponent,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

Now i would like to view Page1Component in 'mynamed' outlet and HomeComponent.
How would a routerLink look like ?

I tried :

```
[routerLink]="['guide','main','form', 'first', {outlets: {mynamed: ['page1']}} ]"
```

but no luck

Edit 2 (my solution):

```
[routerLink]="['guide','main','form', 'first' ]"
```

This opens the page in unnamed outlet ...

```
[routerLink]="['guide','main',{outlets: {mynamed: ['page1']}} ]"
```

This opens the page in mynamed outlet without affecting the main outlet

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: So i basicly have two named outlets in one of them i have a lot of components to display (views, lists, forms ...) and i want to order them somehow to make it more readable and the urls to look something like ..../add/item  .../view/item and so on, all the while keeping the same data in the other named outlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a route in your `app-routing.module.ts`: 
`{ path: '%urlName%', component: %ComponentName%, outlet: '%routerOutletName%' }`

Then in your template you can use:
`[routerLink]="['page1', 'page2', {outlets: {%routerOutletName%: ['%urlName%']}}]`

And in your `.ts` file you can use to navigate to the route:
`this.router.navigate(['page1', 'page2', { outlets: { %routerOutletName%: ['%urlName%'] } }]);`

[Source](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet), [Example](http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/)

Comment: So my solution isn't possible ?